# Lombok AnnotationProcessor failing with Bazel build

Tags: java, build, bazel, java-11, lombok

I have configured lombok through java plugin and trying to build my bazel project, but it is failing with the following error.  I tried multiple config changes but none of them are working.

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
> make field private
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs
> accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @21a772cf

```
java_plugin(
    name = "lombok_plugin",
    processor_class = "lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor",
    deps = [
        "lombok-1.18.6.jar" ,
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "worker_lib",
    srcs = glob(["**/src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    plugins = [":lombok_plugin"],  # Apply the Lombok plugin
    deps = ["//backend/common"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Comment: You can reference the compiler args specified in the referred link. That should help resolve the exception. On the other hand, upgrading the dependency version might be a better option.

Comment: I upgraded to latest version and tried all the above options mentioned in the link, still I am getting the same error

Comment: Did you ensure `--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED` compiler arg? If so, please update the question with a your latest attempt and reproducible code.

Comment: yeah...I added it in java_library target within add_opens parameter, I am using JDK17 and latest bazel version, tried with all lombok versions from 1.18.10 to 1.18.32, however I am getting slightly different error now ----  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError:  class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x37449386) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassWriter (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.jvm to unnamed module @0x37449386

Comment: As much as I could infer, most of these are due to the fact that Lombok is getting resolved on classpath. The workaround for these packages would be similar with something like `add_exports` parameter for the mentioned packages in the exception you have shared